# Retrieving distinct record from inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to retrieve the first image from `portfolio_images`, and my following query isn't doing that. It's returning all images for each `portfolio` record found (this works with DISTINCT), when I only need the first `portfolio_images.fullsize` record it finds.

**portfolio**

```
id | project_name | location_id | project_type | is_active
```

**portfolio_images**

```
id | portfolio_id | fullsize

 SELECT DISTINCT p.project_name, pi.fullsize
    FROM portfolio p
    INNER JOIN portfolio_images pi ON p.id = pi.portfolio_id
    AND p.is_active = 1
    AND p.project_type = 'project' AND p.location_id = 3
    ORDER BY p.oindex
```

I want to avoid having to query `portfolio` first, then looping through those results and doing a nested loop to query `portfolio_images` for the first returned record based on the current portfolio ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a subquery that gets the last ID for each `portfolio_id` on table `portfolio_images`. this will assure that you will get one record for each `project_name`.

```
SELECT  p.project_name, pi.fullsize
FROM    portfolio p
        INNER JOIN portfolio_images pi 
            ON p.id = pi.portfolio_id AND 
                p.is_active = 1 AND 
                p.project_type = 'project' AND 
                p.location_id = 3
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  portfolio_id, MAX(ID) max_ID
            FROM    portfolio_images 
            GROUP BY portfolio_id
        ) a ON pi.portfolio_id = a.portfolio_id AND
                pi.ID = a.max_ID
ORDER   BY p.oindex
```

Comment: Amazing response. I rarely get to see queries this in-depth in my work.

Comment: It does! I have to wait 3 more minutes before I can accept as my answer.

Comment: oh glad to hear that `:D` happy to helped you.

Comment: by the way, if you want to ding the first `ID`, you can just just `MAX(ID)` into `MIN(ID)`